# Reuse and Interact With Multi-Layer Tile Maps

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

I'm new to game development and try to make a game where buildings are created in tile maps. My problem is that I need to interact with these buildings and I want to reuse the buildings I created.
Now I would like to export these two layers to a single sprite or prefab to create multiple buildings and to make them clickable.

Is there a way to achieve this or do I have the wrong approach?

EDIT:
My current setup looks like this:

Two tile maps: One tile map contains the wall of the building. Another tile map contains decoration like door or window.

My problem is, that I am not able to export these tile maps as one prefab to reproduce it or to attach scrips.
I am looking for a way to combine these two layers into one resource (=The building with all its decorations, doors, windows), so that I can place them anywhere I want and make them clickable as a game object.

Comment: It's unclear to me where you've run into trouble making this setup in Unity. Can you walk us through the steps you've taken so far, what your current setup looks like, and how its behaviour differs from what you need?

Comment: I have made some changes to my question. I hope it is more clear now.